# Did the flood gates open?

Tags: discussion, review

Just wondering as the question states. 323 new first posts in the review option so a lot of first time visitors?

On a side note, would having the ability to review more than 20 posts in a day be helpful? I have been curious as to how 20 was established and why 20 is the daily limit?

Comment: Its just a periodic script that checks for new questions that brings it up - its meant to get reviews on old questions that are first posts I guess.  Same thing's happened on SF. Keep calm and carry on ;p

Comment: I myself was surprised to see ~250 first post reviews when I looked.  On the plus side, it exposed me to a lot of questions that I probably wouldn't have otherwise seen, I guess.  I got some good edits, comments, and flags out of having such a broad field of things to scrutinize.  But, it does make me wonder if maybe there is a way to "unofficially" review more items of the same category, where there is no perk for reviewing, and the actions don't count as a review, but the exposure, and maybe other benefits remain.  Like edits, votes, and flags.

Comment: So, how about the limit by day? How did 20 become the magic number I wonder?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173894/sudden-spike-in-the-number-first-posts-in-the-stackoverflow-review-queue

Comment: Yeah, that was weird, for sure; I saw it on U&L, which tends to have a lot less items in the review queue even than Superuser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the result of a bug having been fixed; new questions [were not being added to the First Posts queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173886/first-posts-review-queue-is-not-showing-first-questions).  The behavior you experienced is by design.

The 20 reviews per day limit exists to allow everyone a fair chance at reviewing posts, rather than [becoming limited to a few users who end up dominating the review tasks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87861/why-are-suggested-edit-votes-limited/102223#102223).  This ensures that a broad set of users perform the review tasks.

Comment: This has happened before. Regression?